# Is it possible to adapt wget's progress bar to several files?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, wget

I'm downloading all the ".htm" files of some directories by doing more or less:

`wget http://some/url/ -r  --accept="*.htm" -nv --show-progress`

In which i turned off wget's printing but kept the progress bar which is useful in my case (`-nv --show-progress`)

This works great but outputs a progress bar for *every* downloaded file.
Is it a possible to have a *single* progress bar that would take into account the sum of all the sizes of the files?

I looked at the the `progress=TYPE` option but this only seems to setup the style of the progress bar and not the total amount of downloaded data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, currently there is no way in Wget to have a single aggregate bar.

However, you can try the alpha version of [Wget 2.0](https://gitlab.com/gnuwget/wget2). It's not exactly what you're looking for, but comes very close. It has been packages as Wget2 in Debian and is available on Arch Linux's AUR. I'm not sure about other distros.

`wget2` supports parallel downloads and HTTP/2 by default and a line under the progress bars showing some aggregate stats. For example:

```
$ wget2 --progress=bar "example.com/?"{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
index.html?8         100% [========================================================================================================================>]     606    32,88KB/s
index.html?5         100% [========================================================================================================================>]     606    18,49KB/s
index.html?6         100% [========================================================================================================================>]     606    31,15KB/s
index.html?7         100% [========================================================================================================================>]     606    32,88KB/s
index.html?4         100% [========================================================================================================================>]     606    34,81KB/s
                          [Files: 9  Bytes: 5,33K [11,78KB/s] Redirects: 0  Todo: 0  Errors: 0                                       ]
```

You see 5 progress bars because 5 threads were used to download the 9 files in parallel. The last bar indicates aggregate stats.

You can easily build Wget2 from git or using the v1.99 tarball available here: https://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget2-1.99.0.tar.gz

DISCLAIMER: I maintain both GNU Wget and Wget2.

Comment: wget2 is very good! It helped me minimizing download times while maximizing bandwidth usage with minimum CPU usage (under 10%) on AWS EC2 t2.medium, even with 20 threads. The progress indicator (total files / files left) is great.

Answer (score 0):

here is a snippet from a script I wrote to move files across multiple protocols.

###### URI -> STD.OUT

wget -O - --reject "index.*" -q --show-progress --no-parent "${url}" 2>/dev/null

###### URI -> F/S (solution)

echo "mget : ${url} ==> ${destination}" 2>&1
wget -r --reject "index.*" -q --show-progress  --no-parent "${url}" -P "${destination}" 2>&1 | pv --progress 1>/dev/null

it works for me.