# Parallel curl (or wget) downloads

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I have a file with 2192 urls, one on each line. I am trying to download them in parallel like this:

`cat urls.txt  | tr -d '\r' | xargs -P 8 -n 1 curl -s -LJO -n -c ~/.urs_cookies -b ~/.urs_cookies`

However, after counting all of the files once they are downloaded `ls -1 | wc -l`, I only have 1400 files. I know that the URLs are all properly formatted (they were autogenerated by the website where I am downloading the data from).

I can rerun the above command and get a few more files each time, but this is not sufficient. Further, downloading the files one at a time would be an option, but the server takes about 30 seconds to **respond** to the request, but each file only takes about 2 seconds to download. I have at least 5 files with 2192 URLs each. I would very much like to do a parallel download.

Can anyone help me figure out why parallel downloads would stop early?

Comment: If you are open to using other tools, [aria2](https://aria2.github.io/) might work..

Comment: What exit code does the xargs return? Perhaps there is a way to wrap the curl calls to see what exit codes the failing curl calls have as well...

Comment: No errors are printed. I can download the files one by one with no problem.

Comment: Not the printed errors but the process exit code. If you `man xargs` and see the EXIT STATUS section or `man curl` and see the EXIT CODES section.

Comment: Neither error nor exit codes are indicated in a way that I can find. I had been trying to do 2 of these parallel downloads at once. I reduced it to one and so far it is continuing to run. Maybe the server shut down connections to me

Comment: To see the exit code of xargs, the `$?` variable contains the exit code from the last command run. I'm not sure how to get the exit code of the curl commands. Maybe [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344360/collect-exit-codes-of-parallel-background-processes-sub-shells) would be helpful.

Comment: If you look at the mentions of using gnu `parallel` (instead of xargs) on the page i linked to in my comment above, and use the `--joblog` flag, it looks like it will give you the exit code of every job, which sounds like it might be what you want.

Comment: since the command has been running for close to 20 minutes now, I'm going to assume that I made the remote server mad by making too many requests. The command above does indeed make parallel requests. I just have to not run that command on 3 files across 3 terminal sessions. I will look into the parallel command as well. Thank you.

Comment: Not a programming question - this is about using existing programs, isn't it?

Comment: Rather than closing, it would be nice if the question could just be moved to Super User

Comment: I would be looking into whether several commands are writing `~/.urs_cookies` at the same time, and trampling each other's changes. Perhaps you could just create this file once, then run parallel processes which only read from this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're okay with a (slightly) different tool, may I recommend using GNU Wget2? It is the spiritual successor to GNU Wget. It is already available in the Debian and OpenSUSE repositories and on the AUR

Wget2 provides multi-threaded downloads out of the box with a nice progress bar to view the current status. It also supports HTTP/2 and many other newer features that were nearly impossible to add into Wget.

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49386440/952658 for some more details.

With Wget2, you can simply run `$wget2 -i urls.txt` and it will start downloading your files in parallel.

EDIT: As mentioned in the other answer, a disclaimer: I maintain both Wget and Wget2. So I'm clearly biased towards this tool

Comment: Thanks, I will try that soon. My downloads finished last night but this is only the first round of downloading that I have to do